# Should a computer be rebooted after changing proxy settings in Internet Options?

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer-11, internet-options

I'm looking for a little bit of best-practice advice. Unfortunately, Google has been polluted by a bunch of people having issues maintaining proxy settings after a reboot. That's not my issue.

My question is: should I trust Internet Options to be smart and start using or not using a proxy right away? Or, is it a good practice to reboot the computer after making proxy changes? I know it's technically not required to reboot after changing proxy settings. I just want to make sure it's definitely using or not using the proxy.

I have to enable proxy settings to do Windows updates, but then have to disable the proxy for security reasons when the updates are finished. I want to make sure the proxy is completely off when I've finished with my work.

Comment: In general, Reboot is not required after changing proxy settings but sometimes due to any issue, settings not get apply properly. In that case, You need to check the related settings to find the cause for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy settings are applied right away. This doesn't require a reboot.